# How can be the best way to create constants in Java program?

Tags: java, singleton, constants

I have two alternatives:

**First: with Singleton design pattern**

```
public class A{
   private static A instance;
   private A(){};
   public A getDefault(){
   if(instance == null)
      instance = new A();
   return instance;
   }
//cst
public static final String cst = "sample";
}
```

In that way, we get access to `cst` via `A.getDefault().cst`

**Second: Reference to the class**

```
public class B{
   public static final String cst = "sample";
}
```

In that way, we get accessed to `cst` via `B.cst`, simply.

What is the best way taking into consideration **performance** (constants for me are numbered and having Image types)?

Comment: Um, the second version?

Comment: Performance is not even a consideration. You seem to not account for the JIT... Also, your singleton code is not thread safe.

Comment: In first solution, we need to have an instance but not in the second, isnt it? @fge

Comment: @HoussemBdr, as it stands now, you don't need an instance in the first case either, since the field is public static there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second alternative (a plain public final static field) is simpler and most likely more efficient.

Should you find yourself in need of a more flexible solution, I would advice you to create an enum to hold your values.

```
public enum MyConstants {
    CST1(new Image("someImage.jpg")),
    CST2(new Image("someOtherImage.jpg"));

    public final Image img;

    private MyConstants(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

Note that both the static field and enum solution can be used elegantly with static imports:

```
import static pkg.B.cst;           // usage:  cst
```

or

```
import static pkg.MyConstants.*;   // usage:  CST1  or  CST2
```

Comment: Or a properties file.

Comment: The values are images though.

Comment: But that point is not clear : `new copy of the constants each time they are accessed,`

Comment: No reason you couldn't load the paths to the images from a properties file... instead of hardcoding them as constants (if you want to more flexible).

Comment: @HoussemBdr, A.getDefault() will create a new A-object each time it's called. Looking at the code, you probably meant to make the instance variable static.

Comment: Yes, I meant static, UPDATED then

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, sure. The initialization of the constants is a slightly different story, and the use of a property file could be combined with all ways of representing the values mentioned so far.

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference is probably unmeasurable. I would prefer the second. You can also use `import static` like

```
import static B.cst;
```

then you can use `cst` directly. Finally, I recommend you make it all upper-case `CST`.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler is better. If it's just a constant, you don't need anything fancier than a straight-forward `public static final String cst = "sample";`.

Answer (score 1):

Although the simpler is enough, you can add a private constructor. This has two advantages. First, nobody can create an instance of B. Second and more important benefit is that nobody can extent B. Therefore B is just a constant value class in your project.